# Installation of python google api in Ubuntu

Tags: python, google-api, ubuntu-14.04

Below command is used for installing Google-API in python for Linux.

```
  pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Below errors are shown by above command

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
>
> status = self.run(options, args)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
>
> requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) sudo -E pip install --upgrade pip

2) sudo -E pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Than environmental variables using flag -E is better

Comment: -E is used when you are using proxy environment.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember there would be many errors and disparencies if you try to install packages without virtual environment in python.

I would like you to create a virtual environment as specified in the link and then try it out.

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/